# Java: Change code by String

Tags: java, list

I have the this line of code:

```
String msg = "What's the capital in " + nyttLista.get(slumpLand).land + "?";
```

I want to switch between `.land` and `.stad`. Can I do this without having to do a duplicate this line of code?

I tried creating a `String` that switch between "land" and "stad":

```
String i = "land";
nyttLista.get(slumpLand).i;
```

Can I do something similar?

Comment: What do you mean by "switch between `.land` and `.stad`"?

Comment: what factor decides whether to use `.land` or `.stad` ?

Comment: It's better to use not English and Dutch (or any other language) mixed; why not use country and city?

Comment: Trying to use a string as a field name like that won't work. in Java.

Comment: You could always go down the road of [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). But if you are just learning Java, I would not recommend this.

Comment: @Turing85 It's never too early to learn reflection! :D

Comment: I've seen some suggestions of reflection, which I would personally avoid unless I really can't help it. I personally mainly use it in UnitTests and when I consider using reflection in my regular code-project, it usually means I have something wrong in my architecture and need to rethink things through. In you case, something as simple as an if-statement (probably a ternary operator with `? :`), an enum, or something similar would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options, each with their own advantages and drawbacks.

The simplest, and almost certainly right for your use case is a **simple "if" statement**.

```
SomeObject obj = nyttLista.get(slumpLand);
String value;
if(<some condition>) {
   value = obj.land;
} else {
   value = obj.stad;
}
String msg = "What's the capital in " + value + "?";
```

If is straight forward, readable but a little verbose and if you add lots of different conditions it will explode.

You can make it shorter using the **ternary operator**:

```
SomeObject obj = nyttLista.get(slumpLand);
String msg = "What's the capital in " + (<some condition> ? obj.land : obj.stad) + "?";
```

but at the cost of readability and extendibility (the latter may not be important for you).

You can use **reflection**:

```
String fieldToUse = <some logic to return "land" or "stad".
Field field = SomeObj.class.getField(fieldToUse);
SomeObject obj = nyttLista.get(slumpLand);
"What's the capital in " + field.get(obj).toString() + "?";
```

I'd not do this in this use case, but it can be useful when you have TEH DYNAMICS (this is so bloody rare that you can ignore this option).

If using Java 8 you could use **Functions and other fun stuff** (or a [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)). But really only for the lolz.

```
Function<SomeObject, String> using;
if(<some condition>) {
   using = (a) => a.land;
} else {
   using = (a) => a.stad;
}


"What's the capital in " + using.apply(nyttLista.get(slumpLand)) + "?";
```

It is useful when you have a lot of different options or you want to pass in part of the algorithm.

You could use a **rules engine**, but we were getting silly at reflection. Great when you have tons of rules, but pointless in the problem above.

You could **push the logic up**. So `SomeObject` has a `getThingie` method that knows when to return `land` or `stad`. Internally it would be implemented using one of the above, but the caller does not need to care. I don't know the logic required to decide on `land` or `stad`, but this is likely the one I'd recommend, implemented internally using a `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible the way you are trying to achive it.

But you could write it like this. Basicly, instead of accessing the variable directly, it is just using method with a variable as a paramter. Based on this paramter, which can be passed with a constant flag it would determine what it would have to return.

```
public class Test {

    private String a = "A";
    private String b = "B";

    public static final int LAND = 0;
    public static final int STAD = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        int option = Test.LAND;
        System.out.println(test.getValue(option));
        option = Test.STAD;
        System.out.println(test.getValue(option));
    }

    public String getValue(int option) {
        if(option == LAND) {
            return a;
        } else if (option == STAD) {
            return b;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brrr ... Using `int` constants instead of an `enum` in the year 2015 is very deprecated. Remember: Enums were introduced with Java 5 in 2004!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose that´s true, but it´s still an option. Espacially since this seems like a question asked by a java starter who can still adopt to enums.

Comment: But why not directly show him the recommended approach, _especially since he seems to be a Java starter_?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this task using reflection.

Store variable name in one variable like in my case it's 'variabeName' and depending upon the value of that variable you will get the value of corresponding fieeld.

```
String variableName="land";
Field[] fields = nyttLista.get(slumpLand).getClass().getFields();
String name = fields[0].getName();
Object value = fields[0].get(obj);

String msg = "What's the capital in " + value.toString() + "?";
```

Comment: You basically copied @SalaryNotFound 's answer. It is not necessary to post the same answer twice.

Comment: My bad!!! I just prepared the answer and posted it,forget to check it was already there!!!

Comment: Like SalaryNotFound, this would not work, but for a different reason. SalaryNotFound does not call `get`, you don't select the right field. Together you have a working solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
String msg = "What's the capital in " + 
    (i.equals("land") ?
        nyttLista.get(slumpLand).land :
        nyttLista.get(slumpLand).stad)
    + "?";
```